# Using group_concat in left join

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I think I might be trying to be too sneaky with my code :p 
I'm trying to link 2 tables together one with 1 row and another with several. But I only want to return one row for the first table and the other. So I'm trying to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to change my join into a single row like so:

```
col 1 || col 2 || col 3 (linked)
----------------------------------
  23  ||  Data ||  data, data, data
```

Then later I can break this up.

I think the problem is, is this only really works if you have something to join to? If I have no joining rows then they seem to be ignored? Of if I do this in the sub query it returns null?

This is my queries

sub query

```
SELECT * FROM wp_fishy_posts p 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.path,',') AS linked_images,l.postID as link_id 
        FROM wp_fishy_images i 
        LEFT JOIN wp_fishy_images_post_link l ON l.imageID=i.ID) AS l ON l.link_id=p.ID
    WHERE p.post_type='image'
```

Returns null when rows are joined?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.path,',') AS linked_images,p.*
FROM wp_fishy_posts p
(SELECT i.path,l.postID as link_id 
    FROM wp_fishy_images i 
    LEFT JOIN wp_fishy_images_post_link l ON l.imageID=i.ID) AS l ON l.link_id=p.ID
WHERE p.post_type='image'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? :S Thanks in advance!

Comment: The group_concat is used with a group by, not necessarily with a join (although the query could contain a join)

Comment: if you know the other two tables are 1-to-1, there should be no need for a subquery. And, like most aggregate functions, GROUP_CONCAT should ignore nulls unless no non-null values are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `group by` in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_fishy_posts p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.path,',') AS linked_images, l.postID as link_id 
      FROM wp_fishy_images i LEFT JOIN
           wp_fishy_images_post_link l
           ON l.imageID = i.ID
      GROUP BY l.postId
------^
     ) l
     ON l.link_id = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'image';
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise I needed a group by :)